# Visio 2007 - Can't find website mapping feature

Tags: microsoft-visio

I understand that the Web Site Map template is in the Software/Database template category. However, when I select File, New, I do not have Software/Database as an option for a template Category. I have Business, Flowchart, General, Maps and Floor Plans, Network, and Schedule.  I've checked all the category options and none contain a Web Site Map template.

Is there an add-on or a template download that I could install?

Thanks, 
Catie

Answer (score 0):

From your categories I understand that you have Visio Standart installed. Software/Database category and related diagrams are provided only in Visio Professional.

You can see the full feature and diagram comparison charts here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896660

If it's a one time job you can download 30 day trial of Visio Professional.

Alternatively, I can recommend [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/). It's a free online diagram application that has a basic Web Site Map template.